# Prevent user from accessing /auth/:provider under some conditions in OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, rack

Is there any way to prevent users from accessing `/auth/:provider` if, say, they are not logged in? I've tried to use `before_request_phase` callback and `Rack::Response` to redirect them to sign in page but it haven't worked.

My application is not using omniauth for user authentication. Instead, it is used to connect third-party accounts to the user profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution I found was to create a new OmniAuth Strategy which inherits from the one I wanted to use and to override the `request_phase` method. Could not get the same behaviour using only OmniAuth configs in its initializer.

```
def request_phase
  if env['rack.session']['warden.user.user.key'].present?
    super
  else
    redirect '/'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
OmniAuth.config.before_request_phase = lambda do |env|
  user = env['warden'].authenticate!
end
```